# Display table cell equal height bleeds over the container IE and FF

Tags: css

I am working on 3 different grid layouts , floated , flex and table. Floated and flex work as intended but the display table based grid the cell is bleeding over the table in IE and FF. Task for flex and table grid is to have the columns and columns-in equal height. Flex grid does this without thinking but table based grid is causing some trouble.

https://jsfiddle.net/Themezly/ux2ewy6v/

while this works fine in other browsers this is what I see in IE and FF

[image]

I have tried to vertically align the cell in the middle and that "kinda" fixes it in IE but FF wont play ball.

[image]

Please note that given structure is using column-in for styling and I cant do `overflow:hidden;` on column or row due to possible borders and box shadows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I checked it in FF 47 and IE 11 and I don't see any problem

Comment: Chrome too. Same result everywhere.

Comment: I might be going crazy but I see the images in post on Edge and FF 50

Comment: @MrLister stretch the fiddle screen please

Comment: Still seeing the same thing. The four `column-in` blocks have the same height in every browser. (Which is the height of the table cells, only the column-in blocks are pushed down, overflowing out of the cells because of their top margins.)